# Syntax Error: (10,2) Expected identifier, got 'if' In ROBLOX STUDIO

Tags: roblox

I am creating a game in which you need to kill a bunch of Pirates, but the error:

> Syntax Error: (10,2) Expected identifier, got 'if'

appears when I run this script (code below):

```
dead_bool = game.ServerScriptService.deadBool.Value
print(dead_bool)

NPC_died = 0

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    local killed = game.Players.
    
    if script.Parent.Humanoid ~= nil then
        if script.Parent.Humanoid.Health <=0 then
            NPC_died.Value += 1
            dead_bool = true
            if dead_bool then
                kills.Value +=1
                wait(0.1)
                script:remove()
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And yeah the dead_bool value is in the right place so yeah please help.

it was supposed yo display as either true or false but its giving me an error, just please help fix it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you is having is is becaus is a syntax error is in your code. Is in is LuaUU, you need to provide an identifier (a variable name) after the `local killed = game.Players.` line. Currently, there is a missing identifier, causing the syntax error.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```lua
local dead_bool = game.ServerScriptService.deadBool.Value
print(dead_bool)

local NPC_died = 0

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    local killed = game.Players.LocalPlayer -- Add an identifier here

    if script.Parent.Humanoid ~= nil then
        if script.Parent.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
            NPC_died.Value += 1
            dead_bool = true
            if dead_bool then
                kills.Value += 1
                wait(0.1)
                script:remove()
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In the corrected code, I added `LocalPlayer` as the identifier for `game.Players.`. You can modify it according to your requirements.

Additionally, note that `NPC_died` is assigned a value of 0, but later in your code, you're trying to increment `NPC_died.Value` as if it were a Roblox DataStore object. If you intended to use a DataStore, make sure to properly handle it and initialize it correctly.

Comment: So does that mean that an identifier is a variable? And that there was an error because i added an extra dot? Thank you by the way, it worked!